# NewLine on CSV export of datatable

Tags: c#, csv, datatable, export, .net-4.5

I have a datatable in a .Net web app that my customers have the option to export to CSV. A few customers have complained that the CSV is not able to re-import to our application. after further review, I noticed that on some large exports, the file has line breaks in it. is there a way i can prevent this?

here is my export method

```
DataTable dt = (DataTable)Session["Findings"];
            string fileName = "test.csv";
            string delimiter = ",";
            //prepare the output stream
            Response.Clear();
            Response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
            Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
            Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition",
                string.Format("attachment; filename={0}", fileName));

            //write the csv column headers
            for (int i = 0; i < dt.Columns.Count; i++)
            {
                Response.Write(dt.Columns[i].ColumnName);
                Response.Write((i < dt.Columns.Count - 1) ? delimiter : Environment.NewLine);

            }

            //write the data
            foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < dt.Columns.Count; i++)
                {
                    Response.Write("\"" + row[i].ToString() + "\"");
                    Response.Write((i < dt.Columns.Count - 1) ? delimiter : Environment.NewLine);
                }
            }

            Response.End();
```

any help would be appreciated.

thanks